# I get this error when i try to ban someone from auditlog action 'member_descriptor' object has no attribute 'ban'

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    entry = await channel.guild.audit_logs(action=dis.AuditLogAction.channel_delete, limit=1).get()
    member = entry.user.name
    member = dis.Member
    print('bann')
    await member.ban(reason='ask own')
```

Comment: In your own words, when you do `member = entry.user.name` and then immediately `member = dis.Member`, what effect do you expect this to have? Why do the first assignment if you will immediately replace the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    entry = await channel.guild.audit_logs(action=dis.AuditLogAction.channel_delete, limit=1).get()
    member = await channel.guild.fetch_member(entry.user.id)
    print('bann')
    await member.ban(reason='ask own')
```

You shouldn't use `entry.user.name` because this will give you the **name of the user as a `string`**. If you use `entry.user` instead, you will get the `discord.Member` object and you won't have to use `member = dis.Member`.

Comment: it gives error saying object 'User' has no attribute 'ban'

Comment: it says 'missing permissions' but it has administrator and ban members

Comment: Remember that the bot's role has to be higher than the highest role the user you want to ban has.

Comment: it is higher then any role